# Maven does not see testng tests when testing Spring Boot Application is running

Tags: spring-boot, maven, testng

I setup simple Spring Boot project to serve basic HTML pages. I wrote a kind of integration tests with testNG. Now, I want to run my tests with maven does not see my tests.

**STR:**

1. Run `mvn spring-boot:run`
2. Run `mvn test`

**Output:**

```sh
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------------< vznd:selenium >----------------------------
[INFO] Building selenium 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ selenium ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 27 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ selenium ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ selenium ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\vladyslav.kovalenko\OneDrive - FORM.com\Documents\den\selenium-webdriver-tests\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ selenium ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test (default-test) @ selenium ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.963 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-09T13:03:51+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>vznd</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M6</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <testng.version>7.5</testng.version>
        <selenium-java.version>3.141.59</selenium-java.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.11.0</commons-io.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.chrome.driver>/tmp/chromedriver/chromedriver</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

**testng.xml:**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="SeleniumApp Tests" parallel="false">
    <test name="Selenium Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="vznd.selenium.AlertsControllerTest"/>
            <class name="vznd.selenium.GettingBrowserInformationTest"/>
            <class name="vznd.selenium.FramesTest"/>
            <class name="vznd.selenium.BrowserNavigationTest"/>
            <class name="vznd.selenium.KeyboardActionsTest"/>
            <class name="vznd.selenium.WindowsTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Test example:**

```java
package vznd.selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FramesTest extends BaseTest {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void openPageWithIframes() {
        driver.get(HTMLPath.FRAMES);
    }

    @Test
    public void switchToFrameUsingWebElement() {
        WebElement greenFrame = driver.findElement(By.id("first-iframe"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(greenFrame);
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table[id='green-table']"));
        Assert.assertNotNull(table, "The table WebElement object was null!");
    }

}
```

**Spring Boot Application:**

```java
package vznd.selenium;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SeleniumApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SeleniumApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller example:**

```java
package vznd.selenium.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class FramesController {

    @GetMapping("/iframes")
    public String iframes() {
        return "iframes";
    }

}
```

I tried to google about similar problems, but most answers is about naming test classes with *Test suffix and that is not my case.

The tests are executed in IDEA by right-click on the project -> Run -> All tests.

Please, advice me how I can get tests executed with maven.

Comment: did you found why?

Answer (score 2):

If you see the logs `surefire` is not detecting TestNG.
`Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider`

If you remove SpringBoot will be: `Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider`

Try adding TestNG dependency to surefire plugin:

```
<project>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.chrome.driver>/tmp/chromedriver/chromedriver</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```